# Find and replace string in two different file using tcl?

Tags: tcl

I have 2 files like below:

+file1.txt

```
1.3.1   abc
1.3.2   def
...
```

+file2.txt

```
abc  , value x value y
def  , value a value b
...
```

I want to **replace** the **first occurrence** in line of **abc** in **file2.txt** with **1.3.1** in **file1.txt** so the result of file2.txt should be:

+file2.txt

```
1.3.1  , value x value y
1.3.2  , value a value b
```

I am using TCL for this and I stuck at this:

```
set fileid1 [open "file1.txt" r+]
set fileid2 [open "file2.txt" r+]

set buffer1 [read $fileid1];
set buffer2 [read $fileid2];
set dataline1 [split $buffer1 "\n"]
set dataline2 [split $buffer2 "\n"]


foreach line $dataline2 {

}


close $fileid1
close $fileid2
```

Comment: I made a few changes to the post. Is it ok? Also, will the first line in `file1.txt` also match the first line in `file2.txt`? Or do you have to check every line in `file1.txt` and try to match with the first words/part before the first comma in `file2.txt`?

Comment: file2.txt have many line before and after so it will not match with the first line of file1.txt.

Comment: Any more details? What about the answers you've received?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's one way to do it:**

**Note:** If file1.txt and file2.txt is large, this may not be optimal since it reads all data in one shot. The approach may be changed slightly to read one line at a time from each file.

```
$ cat replace.tcl
proc getReplaceMap {fileName} {
    set fd [open $fileName]
    set data [read $fd]
    close $fd

    array set replaceMap {}
    foreach line [split $data "\n"] {
        set line [string trim $line]
        if {$line eq ""} {
            continue
        }
        set replaceMap([lindex $line 1]) [lindex $line 0]
    }
    return [array get replaceMap]
}

proc getUpdatedLine {line replaceMap} {
    array set replacement $replaceMap
    set lineElements [split $line]
    foreach element [array names replacement] {
        set index [lsearch $element $lineElements]
        if {$index != -1} {
            set lineElements [lreplace $lineElements $index $index $replaceMap($element)]
        }
    }
    return [join $lineElements]
}

proc getUpdatedContents {fileName replaceMap} {
    set fd [open $fileName]
    set data [read $fd]
    close $fd

    set newData {}
    foreach line [split $data "\n"] {
        lappend newData [getUpdatedLine $line $replaceMap]
    }
    return [join $newData "\n"]
}

# Main begins here
set replaceMap [getReplaceMap file1.txt]
set newContents [getUpdatedContents file2.txt $replaceMap]
puts $newContents
# Now write to file
set fd [open file2.txt w]
puts $fd $newContents
close $fd


$
```

**Execution output:**

```
$ tclsh replace.tcl
abc , value x value y
def , value a value b

sharad$ cat file2.txt
abc , value x value y
def , value a value b

$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# read the first file, store data in an array
set fh [open file1.txt r]
array set values {}
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    regexp {(\S+)\s+(\S+)} $line -> value key
    set values($key) $value
}
close $fh

# read the second file, transform it, and write to a new file
set fh [open file2.txt r]
set fout [file tempfile tmpfilename]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    regexp {(\S+)} $line -> firstword
    if {[info exists values($firstword)]} {
        regsub "(?q)$firstword" $line $values($firstword) line
    }
    puts $fout $line
}
close $fh
close $fout

# backup the second file, and replace it with the new data
file rename file2.txt file2.txt~
file rename $tmpfilename file2.txt
```

Afterwards

```
$ cat file2.txt
1.3.1  , value x value y
1.3.2  , value a value b
```

Comment: all commands documented at http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm

Answer (score 0):

Load the keys and replacement values into a dictionary:

```
package require fileutil

foreach {val key} [::fileutil::cat file1.txt] {
    dict set replacements $key $val
}
```

Traverse the other file, looking for keywords and replacing them:

```
set result {}
::fileutil::foreachLine line file2.txt {
    set key [regexp -inline {^\S+} $line]
    if {[dict exists $replacements $key]} {
        lappend result [regsub ^$key $line [dict get $replacements $key]]
    }
}
::fileutil::writeFile file3.txt [join $result \n]
```

The `fileutil` package is a part of the standard library for Tcl, Tcllib.

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lreverse](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreverse.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)